# how to unzip/untar files using Curl in ftp server

Tags: curl, ftp, tar, unzip

In the curl command we can delete,rename and move files from a FTP server using Curl like in the command below:

```
curl -v -u username:pwd ftp://host/FileTodelete -Q "DELE FileTodelete"
```

Can we untar or unzip files like this way ? I mean that instead of `DELE FileTodelete` we put a untar/unzip command to extract a file in a remote server?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functionality to unzip or untar offered by a FTP server and therefore you cannot do it. You might try using the SITE command in case the FTP server is configured to allow unzip/untar with this command but in the common setups this is not possible.